# APIレベル10でのWebView内でAjaxが動かない件

Tags: android, webview, ajax

Android2.3.3(APIレベル10)のWebView内で下記のようなajaxの処理をjavascript内に記述しても
動かないようですが、何か解決策はありますでしょうか？

```
 $.ajax({
            url: https://xxxxxxxx,
            type: "POST",
            timeout:10000,
            cache : false,
            data: {data:xxxx},
　　　　　　 beforeSend: function(xhr) {
              var credentials = $.base64.encode(basic_user+":"+basic_password);
              xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + credentials);
            },
            success: function(result) {
                $("#result").html(result);
            }
    })
```

サーバーからHTMLをレスポンスで返したいと考えております。

**追記：**

Internetパーミッションは、入れております。

ログは下記のとおりです。

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Authorization Required) https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Failed to load resource: Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. index.html:1
```

ベーシック認証がうまく通っていないようでしたので、ベーシック認証を一度外しましたが、
401のエラーが出ないだけで、動きませんでした。。。

Comment: ログは何か出ていたりしませんか？
HTMLをローカルで持っていて、Internetパーミッションの付け忘れというケースなどが見つかります。

Answer (score 1):

[Access-Control-Allow-Origin Error At Android 4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11318703/access-control-allow-origin-error-at-android-4-1)の回答に、掲題のAndroidバージョンでも使用できる解決方法があったのでお試しいただけますか。

@johnnybgoodeさんの方法です。

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
    Class<?> clazz = webView.getSettings().getClass();
    Method method = null;
    try {
        method = clazz.getMethod("setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs", boolean.class);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (method != null) {
        try {
            method.invoke(webView.getSettings(), true);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

リフレクションによる処理なので`ProGuard`を入れておりましたら設定にご注意ください。
try_catchはIDEに従い勝手に入れたので適宜ご変更下さい。

釈迦に説法なのですが、`Failed to load resource: Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin`とはajaxの制約で、違うドメインなどからローカルファイルにアクセスしようとすると、`Same-Origin Policy`によるローカルファイルへのアクセスに反するためにアクセスを拒否されて出力される...エラーらしいです。
`Same-Origin Policy`とはなんだ、`jQuery`でも起きるらしいけどどうして？と色々、勉強させていただきました。

要するに、即席で知識を詰め込んだので動かなかったらすみません。

Comment: @user3009331さん

コメントを書いて頂き、ありがとうございます。
記載して頂いたコードですが、APIレベル16以上の場合の処理のようですが、APIレベル10以上で同じ処理を実装するのは難しいでしょうか？

どうぞ宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。回答にあるソースコードは本家の元コメによれば、  
what to do if I have project under api11?とのコメントにこうすれば動くよと回答したものなので、APIレベル10でも一応動くはずです……質問者様が仰るようにsetAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLsはAPI16から使用可能なメソッドですが、非公開なだけでそれ以前のバージョンでもメソッドはあるらしいです。http://tools.oesf.biz/android-2.3_r1.0/search?q=setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs&defs=&refs=&path=&hist=
リフレクションはそういった隠れAPIにアクセスする裏道ですね。なので、APIレベルが16以上かそれ以下で直接APIを使うか、リフレクションで呼び出しかで制御すればなお良いのでしょうが、回答でも一応動くかと存じます。（動かしてないのでMoSuchErrorと出ていたらごめんなさい。）
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) { はビルドをしたSDKのバージョンで、今の最新は24なのであってもなくても問題ないかなと存じます。